# Autoinstall is failing for Ubuntu Server IoT 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to automate Ubuntu Server 20.04 IoT.
First thing is it doesn't generate `autoinstall-user-data` file for some reason.
Then i used a very basic user-data(added below). It starts installation process and it runs for sometime finally getting error always at this point.

[image]

**autoinstall-user-data**

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    username: ubuntu
```